# Why removing waitKey() in openCV doesn't work?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm starting out with OpenCV with Python 3 and I have the following snippet:

```
import cv2
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    success, captured_frame = video.read()
    cv2.imshow('Video', captured_frame)
    pressed_key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if pressed_key == ord('q'):
    break

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If I remove the `pressed_key` variable along with its condition, the program runs but the Video window is blank and Windows attempts to force quit the program. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

opencv performs window rendering during waitKey times, so you will need at least a waitKey(1) call to see some window content.

Comment: Great and quick answer :) 
Thank you very much!

Comment: if you need a faster processing and think that waitJey slows down more than necessary, you should use/try different renderings, like implementing your own frame buffer writing, or using Qt with an openGL widget.