# Why GUI is getting stucked and background process is running perfectly?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, pyqt5

I write a program like this:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
counter = 1
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret: break
    cv2.imwrite(...)
    self.progressbar.setValue(int((counter / self.totalFrame)*100))
    time.sleep(1)
    counter += 1

self.progressbar.setValue(0)
cap.release()
```

I want to extract all frames from a video using opencv and want to show the progress in a PyQt5 progress bar. I also use sleep to avoid Not Responding. But the program is showing me Not Responding and the progress bar is also getting stucked by the background works are finely done by it.

How can I show the progress in progress bar properly?

self.totalFrame is the number of frames of the video.

The progressbar is getting stucked after progress of 5 or 6 %
[image: The progressbar is getting stucked after progress of 5 or 6 %]
But all frames are getting extraced successfully
[image: But all frames are getting extraced successfully]

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick I have posted two ss. Is it enough to understand now?

Comment: The fact that you are using a while loop is the main reason for making the ui not responding, as no *blocking* should ever happen in the main UI thread. The same goes for `time.sleep()` which does exactly the opposite of what you think: it **prevents** the UI from updating and being responsive. If you need a *parallel* function that continuously processes something, you need to use a separate "worker" QThread for that, with a custom signal that emits a value for the progress bar. Do some research as there's plenty of posts about this topic even here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @musicamante ok! thanks a lot!

Comment: not sure abour PyQt but in C++ there is a function to temporariliy go back to the event loop from within such a loop so that gui functions are performed/updated

Comment: from the doc: "Long-running operations can call processEvents() to keep the application responsive" maybe you find thr PyQt variant of processEvents() yourself?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Micka, I'll try to find out the Python version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why removing waitKey() in openCV doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59557039/why-removing-waitkey-in-opencv-doesnt-work)

Comment: yes @rayryeng it answers. but now, the gui is showing some activity but getting stucked as it was.

Comment: Open up a new question then.

Comment: ok sure @rayryeng

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace time.sleep(1) with cv2.waitKey(1)

Comment: But another problem, after cv2.waitKey(1), the progressbar is responding, but when I try to move the GUI, it moving after 1/2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Today I got the way how can I run the progress bar properly without implementing QThread.

I have to add `QApplication.processEvents()` after the statement.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
counter = 1
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret: break
    cv2.imwrite(...)
    self.progressbar.setValue(int((counter / self.totalFrame)*100))
    QApplication.processEvents()
    counter += 1

self.progressbar.setValue(0)
cap.release()
```